# undefined при попытке получить свойство объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
class submenu {
 constructor(id) {
  $( function () {
   this.elementId = id;
   console.log(this.elementId)
   $( '#' + this.elementId ).children().next().css('display', 'flex');

  } );
 }
}
printMenu = new submenu( 'top-menu-print' );
$(function (){
 console.log(printMenu.elementId)
})
```

консоль внутри класса показывает правильное значение. Но если запросить свойство объекта, он выдаст undefinrd

Answer (score 0):

зачем вам `$( function () {` в конструкторе? `this` будет указывать уже не контекст этой самой функции, а не класса.

```js
class submenu {
  constructor(id) {
    //$( function () {
      this.elementId = id;
      console.log(this.elementId)
      $('#' + this.elementId).children().next().css('display', 'flex');

    //} );
  }
}
printMenu = new submenu('top-menu-print');
$(function() {
  console.log(printMenu.elementId)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top-menu-print">test</div>
```

Если сильно хочется, то надо сохранить контекст вызова:

```js
class submenu {
  constructor(id) {
    let self = this;
    $(function() {
      self.elementId = id;
      console.log(self.elementId)
      $('#' + self.elementId).children().next().css('display', 'flex');

    });
  }
}
printMenu = new submenu('top-menu-print');
$(function() {
  console.log(printMenu.elementId)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top-menu-print">test</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое